# JQuery SlideUp/SlideDown works ocassionaly

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

The dev site is this:
https://bcdev01.alpineincdev.com/

If you hover over the cart area (top right), a new div slides down covering the trigger area. When mouse leaves the new div, it's supposed to slide up.

Sometimes this function works. Sometimes it doesn't slide up but stuck in the extended position. Other times, but not always (in Firefox), it goes up and down continuously.

What gives?

The Jquery code is below

```
 <script>
jQuery.noConflict();

 // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    jQuery("#minicart_trigger").hover(
        function () {
          jQuery("#minicart").slideDown("slow");  
        }
      );

    jQuery("#minicart").mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery("#minicart").slideUp("slow");
    });


 });
```

Any idea of why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Prototype acting up: `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object`

Comment: You may want to use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function to end any current animations, before calling `.slideUp()`/`.slideDown()`.

Answer (score 1):

replace with this:

```
jQuery("#minicart_trigger").hover(function () {
        jQuery("#minicart").stop().slideDown("slow");  
    },function() {
        jQuery("#minicart").stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: I meant to say, thanks for the answer. But in Firefox, the #minicart would slide down but stop roughly where my cursor is. It doesn't extend all the way. Not sure why. It works fine in Chrome, however.

Comment: can you paste relevant html and css or make fiddle.